# Firebase Cloud Messaging error: more than one library with package name 'com.google.android.gms'

Tags: android, google-play-services, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have a project that uses Google Firebase Messaging. I followed the documentation and it worked like a charm. The problem is that to build it on the server, I need to add the .aar files manualy, so I checked the gradle dependency tree and added the needed dependencies as shown in the image:

firebase-messaging dependencies
[image]

The problem is that when I try to compile, I get the following error:

> Error: more than one library with package name
>   'com.google.android.gms'

Error message:
[image]

I checked the other threads in stackoverflow about this error, but none of the solutions worked for me. Here are the dependencies in my gradle file:

```
dependencies {
    debugCompile project(path: ':OrbitEmailCore', configuration: 'debug')
    releaseCompile project(path: ':OrbitEmailCore', configuration: 'release')
    debugCompile project(path: ':OrbitInterOp', configuration: 'debug')
    releaseCompile project(path: ':OrbitInterOp', configuration: 'release')
    compile 'commons-io:commons-io:2.0.1'
    compile files('./libs/docviewer_v4.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:22.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.0.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testCompile 'org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4:1.6.4'
    testCompile 'org.powermock:powermock-mockito-release-full:1.6.4'
    testCompile 'org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito:1.6.4'
    compile project(':firebase-iid-9.8.0')
    compile project(':firebase-messaging-9.8.0')
    compile project(':firebase-common-9.8.0')
    compile project(':play-services-basement-9.8.0')
}
```

I know that this problem usally appears when different versions of dependencies are used, but in my case I am using 9.8.0 for all of them. The problem is with play-service-basement dependency, but if I don't add it my code won't compile because some classes are missing.

The strange thing is that the external libraries folder in my project contains libraries for firebase and play-services for both 9.0 and 9.8, even though I am not declaring them anywhere else in the project.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

Please use

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

below dependencies block and use classpath at the top level build file

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
```

and then sync your project with gradle.

Comment: The problem is that I am using different flavors, so my dependencies are in the main project and then I use a google-services.json for each flavor. So I am dding the

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

line at the end of every flavor build, but it is not detecting the existence of the dependency because it is declared in the main build.gradle file

Comment: I added play-services-basement dependency to the flavor gradle with the apply plugin line at the end, but still having the same error.

If I remove the "apply plugin" line, then the error disapears, but I am not able to get a registration token nor to receive messages.